# A way to offset indexes in OpenCl kernel?

Tags: opencl, gpu

I have a kernel which accepts the following parameters:

1) Global ID is 1040

2) Local ID is 16

Below is not the kernel I am using but I am using it to illustrate what i would like to implement; basically array inputs of A and B are 1040*10 long.

```
__kernel void vector_add(__global const int *A, __global const int *B, __global int *C, int Offset, int constant) {

    // Index of the current element to be processed
    int i = get_global_id(0);


    // Do the operation
    C[i + Offset*constant] = A[i + Offset*constant] + B[i + Offset*constant];
}
```

Whereas constant is a constant, i would like Offset to be an "array" of sorts, containing the values 0,1,...,9. I have already tried passing these values as an array however I don't think it is possible to have an array used for offsetting in this manner (the program crashes). A sample of what I would like to write is below:

```
__kernel void vector_add(__global const int *A, __global const int *B, __global int *C, __constant const int *Offset, int constant) {

    // Index of the current element to be processed
    int i = get_global_id(0);

    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
    // Do the operation
    C[i + Offset[k]*constant] = A[i + Offset[k]*constant] + B[i + Offset[k]*constant];
    }
}
```

Please note: Scaling the Global ID is not an option, since in my kernel it needs to remain fixed. Therefore: is there anyway to achieve this?

EDIT: I added an example of what I would like to implement. Currently, it does not work like this. Is this legal?

Comment: if array elements zero, it shouldn't crash, if crashes when not, then they are out of bounds of buffer

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik   I edited my question, maybe it is clearer. the second kernel I posted isnt working... if you tell me this is legal then I have a problem in my host code

Answer (score 1):

Error message I got is

> parameter cannot be allocated in a named address space

because `constant` is a reserved word.

I tried changing variable name by adding '1' at the end of it as in this:

```
__kernel void vector_add(__global  int *A,       __global  int *B, __global int *C,
                         __constant  int *Offset,__constant  int * constant1) {

    int i = get_global_id(0);
    int constVar=constant1[0];
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        C[i + Offset[k]*constVar] = A[i + Offset[k]*constVar] + B[i + Offset[k]*constVar];
    }
}
```

and it works for global=1040, ABC_size=1040*10, local=16, offset from 0 to 9 array and constant1=1040

Comment: thanks for confirming, but i can't get it to work on my kernel... i will double check my host code

Comment: does it crash again?